# Multiple aggregate functions

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a SQL Server table with `Item`, `Supplier`, `Value` and `Date` columns where are records of all item purchases, I need records, by item, with minimum value of the last 180 days only.

A sample table with only one Item:

```
Item   | Supplier | Value | Date          
---------------------------------------
123    |   28     |  115  | 2013-09-25 
123    |   25     |  125  | 2013-11-30 
123    |   30     |  120  | 2014-01-15 
123    |   25     |  130  | 2014-04-30
```

The query result should be:

```
123    |   30     |  120  | 2014-01-15
```

It is possible have records that seems to be duplicated because it can be more than one origin document from the same supplier and date with same Item and value. Only need one of this records.

How can I get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a ranking function like `Row_Number`:

```
WITH CTE AS
(
  SELECT Item, Supplier,Value, Date,
         RN = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Item
                                 ORDER BY Supplier DESC)
  FROM dbo.TableName
  WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Date, GetDate()) <= 180
)
SELECT Item,  Supplier,Value, Date
FROM CTE
WHERE RN = 1
```

[**Demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b3bc/12/0)

However, it's not that clear what you want of the duplicates or what a duplicate is at all. I have presumed that the `Item` determines a duplicate and that the maximum `Supplier` is taken from each duplicate group.

If you want to use all columns to determine a duplicate your desired result would contain multiple rows because there is no duplicate at all.

Comment: Almost perfect! Thank you @Tim! Only need to change `ORDER BY Value, Date DESC` to serve all my purposes.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way of achieving this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM TableName
WHERE DATEDIFF(day, Date, GetDate()) <= 180
ORDER BY VALUE
```

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/6b3bc/20)

Answer (score 0):

```
select item, supplier, min_value
from
(
select item, supplier, min_value, row_number() over(order by min_value) as row_num
from
(
select item, supplier, min(value) as min_value
from sales
where DATEDIFF(DAY, mydate ,GETDATE()) <= 180
group by item, supplier
) dt
) dt1
where dt1.row_num = 1
```